# Can't make Invisible Text visible (font-size: 0)

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

I'm using Joomla 3 and I created a blog site, I'm using a design-controll tamplate
I created a "new-article" page, but I noticed that some of the buttons don't have text in them, when I checked with firebug I discovered there's a `font-size:0` on them, when I remove the **V** from it in firebug it displays the text. I found the file and the line and deleted ALL the `font-size: 0px;` lines, the simply don't exist in the file, yet the text is still invisible, and when I check Inspect-Elemnt it still shows

how it looks now:

[image]

how it looks when I remove the **V** from `font-size:0` (and how I want it to look)

[image]

[image]

it seriously drives me NUTS

[image]

and here's the file as you can see line 2875 is EMPTY

[image]

I tryed checking on different browsers and different computers, still the text is invisible and Inspect Element shows `font-size: 0px;`

here's the link to the page (it's public now, later on it's supposed to be a members only page)
http://debutinvest.com/new-article

Comment: For a question like this, you would need to provide a link to the website so we can inspect/test it ourselves.

Comment: check for any inline code is present or not.

Comment: There is no inline code but if there was, wouldn't it effect the site even if I remove the V from the line in the Inspect Element window

Comment: I would think you're not finding the right css file. The one you found has margin-top and margin-bottom properties, but the style declaration in firebug doesn't show them - meaning you're not looking at the same declaration block. That and your line numbers don't actually line up (2874 is indeed empty, but inspect will tell you only the # for the beginning of the block - it would be 2873 if the same file)

Comment: It moved because I deleted ALL the font-size:0 lines there were, plus I double and triple checked the file name and location, and I even checked most of the css files and deleted the font-size:0 lines everywhere I could

Comment: Unfortunately the link still goes to a 403 access denied page. Anyway - the margin-top and margin-bottom declarations should still be in inspect if it were locating the same file and block... If inspect is telling you the correct location then that's either truly weird or insanely tedious: javascript could be changing the style declarations on the fly somewhere and removing the margin- styles and adding a font-size:0 property... You'll have to find where in your js that could be happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can overwrite this in your css by adding following, that will overwrite the font-size:0px;

```
.btn-toolbar{
   font-size:12px !important;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I just tried and it didn't work, I simply can't understand what is happening

Answer (score 0):

It would be best to provide a link so that we can inspect ourselves.

You can also look for a `text-indent` with a negative value, typically something like `-999`.

Comment: here's the link to the page (it's public now, later on it's supposed to be a members only page) http://debutinvest.com/new-article